# autoupdate a variable with bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I'd like to know what the procedure is for autoupdating a variable.

For example, I executed

```
./autorefresh.sh
```

and the output to the screen is the variable value:

1

I want it to refresh every 5 seconds incrementing by 1 but I have no idea how to get started. Can anyone offer some assistance?

*** EDIT ***

I figured it out:

```
#!/bin/bash
variable=1
while true
do
clear
echo "your output: " $variable
variable=$((variable=variable+1))
sleep 1
done
```

Comment: What is the content of your script?

Comment: You at least need to learn the bash/scripting basics to unambiguously describe your problem. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Comment: If that is actually an answer to your question then you should add it as an answer and accept it and not edit it into your question.

Comment: This is a simpler way to increment the variable: `((variable++))` without the redundant double assignment.

Comment: Indenting the code inside a loop is always a good idea.  Experienced programmers always indent, people who don't indent do so because they haven't made enough mistakes yet.